# my variable doesn't change even that in the log its say the variable change [unity]

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have 1 script to PlayerMovement and one for powerUp I the power-up code I reference player movement to change the speed and change the bool named timer to true and I write that in log and when I touch the paper the speed doesn't change and the timer don't turn to true but in the log, its say that is yes

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float TargetPos;
    public float Speed;
 
 
    void Start()
    {
 
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
        transform.position = new Vector2(TargetPos, transform.position.y);
    }
 
    public void right()
    {
        TargetPos = transform.position.x + Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    public void left()
    {
        TargetPos = transform.position.x - Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Powrups : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public PlayerMovement pm;
    public float PowerUpActiveTime;
    public float StartPowerUpActiveTime;
    public float peperSpeed;
    float NormalSpeed;
    bool timer;
    bool timerover;
 
 
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.name == "peper")
        {
            pm.Speed = peperSpeed;
            timer = true;
            Debug.Log("timerOn");
            Debug.Log(pm.Speed);
            Debug.Log(timer);
 
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        while(timer)
        {
            GameObject Pause = GameObject.Find("Pause");
            PauseScript pausescript = Pause.GetComponent<PauseScript>();
            if (!pausescript.pause)
            {
                PowerUpActiveTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                if(PowerUpActiveTime <= 0 )
                {
                    timerover = true;
                }
                if (timerover)
                {
                    timer = false;
                }
 
            }
        }
        if (timerover)
        {
            PowerUpActiveTime = StartPowerUpActiveTime;
            pm.Speed = NormalSpeed;
 
 
 
        }
 
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        PowerUpActiveTime = StartPowerUpActiveTime;
        timerover = false;
        NormalSpeed = pm.Speed;
    }
 
 
 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that `while` loop.

You are lucky that until now you probably have tested this always while not being in pause mode ;)

**This `while` would completely freeze your app and the entire Unity Editor!**

In general be extremely careful with `while` loops and nested conditions like here, where the exit condition might never be fulfilled!

What happens currently is that you are not in pause mode so this while loop gets activated and runs until `timer` is set to `false` .. **completely within one single frame**. That is the reason why to you it seems that the value is never `true`.

What you rather want anyway is that code block be executed **once per frame**.

---

And in particular in a frame based application like Unity also have some performance impacts in mind.

You shouldn't use `Find` and `GetComponent` repeatedly within `Update` but store and re-use the results.

---

So your code should rather be

```
// If possible already drag this in via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private PauseScript _pauseScript;

private void Start()
{
    PowerUpActiveTime = StartPowerUpActiveTime;
    timerover = false;
    NormalSpeed = pm.Speed;

    // Get this ONCE as fallback on runtime
    if(!_pauseScript)
    {
        _pauseScript = GameObject.Find("Pause"). GetComponent<PauseScript>();
  
        // Or simply use
        //_pauseScript = FindObjectOfType<_pauseScript>();
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if(timer)
    {
        if (!_pauseScript.pause)
        {
            PowerUpActiveTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(PowerUpActiveTime <= 0 )
            {
                timer = false:
                PowerUpActiveTime = StartPowerUpActiveTime;
                pm.Speed = NormalSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Besides all that, you should rather not let an external power-up control your player values. I would rather go the other way round and have your player object have a component which checks into which power-up items you run and react to it accordingly.

So your power-up itself would actually only be a trigger without any clue if or how exactly the player will be influenced by it.